# How to add new MYSQL row only if it is removed during DELETE and is the last of affected user?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really sorry about the title of this question, I have no idea how to phrase my question. The situation is as follows:

Using PHP and PDO to connect to the database, I have one (InnoDB) table that stores users' group memberships structured like this:

```
Group memberships
+--------+-------+
| member | group |
+--------+-------+
| Tom    |     1 |
| Tom    |     2 |
| Tom    |     3 |
| Anna   |     2 |
| Anna   |     3 |
| Gary   |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```

Now if I want to delete say, group 2 that has been tied into this table through a foreign relation from the groups table, it will automatically delete Gary's, Tom's and Anna's rows from this table.

However, I want to add a row with a predefined group for **all users that have been affected** and no longer have any groups linked. In this case, when group 2 is deleted, another row has to be inserted afterwards for just Gary with id x.

What is the best practice to achieve what I want? I've tried using transactions and manual one-by-one user checks with PHP but it seems very "dirty" and not really that resource-friendly. Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Use an after delete trigger on the groups table to do this or for every user have this record in the membership table regardless of how many other groups a user is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any technical effort if you fix your data model (which should always be the prefered solution, since you asked for best practice).

Add a new table `member (member)` (or `member (id, member)` if you are up to changing the member names in `memberships` to `id` too - would be best practice). Your `group_memberships` should refer to the `member` table with a foreign key (and can use cascaded deletes/updates too).

To get your desired `group_memberships` result that has the additional row if the last entry is deleted, you can now use

```sql
select m.member, g.group 
from member m
left join group_memberships g
on m.member = g.member
```

In case you have no remaining memberships for a `Gary`, this will give you a row `Gary, null`. In case you are doing this to ensure you don't completely delete a user from the database by removing him from all groups, it will already be achieved by having the `member` table, so you maybe don't even need this query to solve your problem.

Comment: There already is a seperate members table that has a foreign key constraint with the "member" field in the membership table. It uses ids instead of names but I simplified for this question! However, members are selected based on their membership and not from the members table directly. Any thoughts on how to implement this with PHP/PDO and how to insert the new row if I do get a NULL value?

Comment: Also, there will be users in the "members" table that will not have any membership assignments. I need the code/query to only take a look at the affected by the DELETE statement.

Comment: @BloodPhilia MySQL cannot insert in the same table on delete. You can still formulate your problem as a relational sql problem with the members table, you could e.g. add a column "was_in_a_group_once" to mark users that were in the membership table once (you can use e.g. a trigger in membership for that), or add a 2nd table. Or you could set your cascade code to "on delete set null" (to not delete your rows) and then tidy up the dublettes regularly afterwards. Or don't use cascades, but delete the memberships in a trigger in your `group` table, there you can count memberships before deletion.

Comment: @BloodPhilia Just to emphasize it again: a problem that can be solved using relation needs good reason to solve it with other means (and it usually pays off in the long run to formulate problems "database friendly", even though it sometimes might look more complicated). That being said, if you still want to do it differently, I gave you 2 alternatives in the comment, and Shadow gave you a third, if you need help with these, ask, I don't want to force you not to do it that way.